# Using DateTime and TimeSpan with non-365 day years

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I am working on a small personal game/project (RPG), and I want the ability to denote how many days are in a year, etc.

At first, I thought that `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` objects would be perfect for my uses, but they appear to be fixed in a 365 day Gregorian Calendar. In a fantasy game, it wouldn't be unusual for a world to have a longer/shorter year (many systems use an "ideal" 360 days, for example).

What are my options for implementation? Is there actually a way to configure these structs to my needs, or should I implement my own methods and classes to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should move for your own method no need of struct, little bit conversion will be required and method will solve the problem hopefully efficiently

Comment: +1 because it's indeed too simple task to search for a wheel, rather make own quick.

Answer (score 2):

Look into NodaTime, it has a CalendarSystem concept that might suit your needs.

http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/userguide/concepts.html

Comment: Yes, except NodaTime does not allow for custom calendars.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is called "day count convention". It's not really hard to implement, and this article can really help you to do it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_count_convention

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` is always Gregorian with its numeric fields, but can use a different calendar when parsing or outputting strings.  See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82aak18x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for working with other calendars in .NET.

There are many built in, or you could consider writing your own custom calendar, by extending `System.Globalization.Calendar`.

`TimeSpan` on the other hand isn't for calendars or dates at all.  It is for *elapsed time*.  It's "day" is simply a 24 hour period, not related to any particular calendar.

Zeeshan is probably correct that you usually don't need to do this.  But I supposed that it depends on how complex your game is.